# How can I check the permission of the File System?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, joomla

When I add a picture in my joomla plugins upladFolder trough ajax it is well done in localhost,

but when I do it in server,the picture is not added.

> Please help me **How can I check the permission of the File System on
>   the server?**

Comment: You can try in Joomla stack: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/ . Also check folder permission. Is it 775?

Comment: First check the folder permission where you are uploading the file! If not then give the permission to that folder Or use this http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php

Answer (score 1):

Try **fileperms()** function.It will return permissions for the given file.

Syntax:

```
fileperms ( string $filename );
```

// Returns the file's permissions as a numeric mode

Ex:

```
<?php
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/tmp')), -4);
echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms('/etc/passwd')), -4);
?>
```

The above example will output:

```
1777
0644
```

[Reference](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fileperms.php)